# Select option change appearance

Tags: html, css, angular

Is it possible to display my dropdown like the picture attached?

[image]
My current dropdown

[image]
How the dorpdown should look like

the code looks like that:

```
   <select #emoji class="textboxclass" type="text" placeholder="Choose your mood" aria-label="Post" formControlName="emoji" required>
            <option value="" selected disabled hidden></option>
            <option *ngFor="let emoji of emojis" [ngValue]="emoji.value">
              {{ emoji.displayValue }}
            </option>
   </select>
```

The following are some of the emoyis I use to display in the dropdown:

```
  emojis = [
      {
        displayValue: '',
        value: 'happy'
      },
      {
        displayValue: '',
        value: 'blushed'
      },
      {
        displayValue: '',
        value: 'grinning'
      },
      {
        displayValue: '',
        value: 'confused'
      },
      {
        displayValue: '',
        value: 'happy3'
      },
      {
        displayValue: '',
        value: 'happy4'
      },
      {
        displayValue: '',
          value: 'happy5'
      },
      {
        displayValue: '',
        value: 'sick'
      },
      {
        displayValue: '',
        value: 'astonished'
      },
      {
        displayValue: '',
        value: 'cold'
      },
      {
        displayValue: '',
        value: 'cry'
      }
  ];
```

Comment: possible add your actual code so can able to help. Create fiddle or snippet.

Comment: i posted the code

Comment: this will not help to solve issue because then user have to create their own list of icons. asking jsfiddle.

Comment: You should create custom template for this rather than using select

Comment: Ok I added the icons

Comment: one mode to avoid this is to create a popup (mat-dialog or bootstrap modal if you use one of these) and display your emoticons as a grid with 8 columns, rennouncing at select.

Comment: Yeah, you won't be able to achieve this using only css and select tags. You will need to develop your own custom dropdown for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: Ahh ok thanks for the tips

Comment: @AlleXyS do you have a tip how to do it with bootstrap modal?

Comment: a good example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49543103/angular-cli-open-component-in-modal. You just pass your array into modal as parameter